# MySQL in Docker returns "The server requested authentication method unknown to the client"

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony4

I use a Docker web stack for Symfony 4 project. MySQL configuration is :

```
mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: sf4_mysql
    volumes:
        - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ***
        MYSQL_USER: ***
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***
```

The pulled image from Docker Hub is MySQL 8 and when I tried to create database with `doctrine:database:create` I received this message :

> 2018-09-17T11:53:51+00:00 [error] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication me
>   thod unknown to the client"
>
> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 126:
>
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 50:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 46:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 46:
>
> PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Answer (score 9):

just update your docker-compose file  as given below and rebuild the image.

```
 mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: sf4_mysql
    volumes:
        - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ***
        MYSQL_USER: ***
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***
```

Comment: it was a life saver.

Comment: But I am getting another error after that. cURL error 7: Failed to connect to ::1: Cannot assign requested address.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 8.0 uses "Pluggable Authentication" - You can solve the issue by taking the following steps.

1. Open your my.cnf and add the following entry (and restart MySQL)

   [mysqld]

   default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
2. Create a user (your MYSQL_USER name) using the correct 8.0 syntax for generating the password (see below)

   IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password

Flush the pivileges and try again.  That should do the trick.