# Unable to login into MySql after changing default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have MySql 8.0 freshly server installed. Initially, I was able to log in, but when I tried to connect to it through PHP PDO I got  this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): The server
>   requested  "authentication method unknown to the client
>   [caching_sha2_password]"

I read from StackOverflow a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367254/mysql-in-docker-returns-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-t)

- Open your my.cnf (in my case the my.ini file) and add the following
  entry (and restart MySQL)
- [mysqld]
- default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
- Create a user (your MYSQL_USER name) using the correct 8.0 syntax for
  generating the password (see below) <---- Altered my existing user
  "root"
- IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
- Flush the privileges and try again.

After I restarted the MySql service I'm now unable to log in to MySQL. with it saying this error now:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

I want to be able to log in through PHP PDO, but I can't even log back in through regular command prompt or MySQL Workbench. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw), not a duplicate, but you'll probably find you have the same issue as the person who asked the question.

Comment: it says to create a new user with "@localhost" I can't even log in to create a new user?

Comment: try maybe resetting the mysql root password? Here's an [article](https://www.a2hosting.co.za/kb/developer-corner/mysql/reset-mysql-root-password) on how to do it via SSH. Is this a linux server?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2, I'll give a try to reset the password.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no good at Windows, wish I could be of more help :)

Comment: @D_Breedt didn't work :( when I stopped the services, and put in the below the [mysqld] "skip-grant-tables", restarted the services and try run it through command line by just going to the bin>mysql I get this error:

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
Then afterwards the MySql server stops.

Comment: What version of PHP?  Do you have `mysqlnd` running with PHP?

Comment: Is your PHP _inside_ the container with MySQL?  Or _outside_?